# Deploying a flutter android app to ios through Xcode

Tags: android, ios, macos, flutter

I managed to build my app on android studio and I managed to get my hands on a mac device too but I am clueless on how to export my app from android studio or flutter to Xcode to build it for IOS 
Is it possible if someone tells me the steps to do this? I searched the internet over and over
thanks in advance

Comment: Just run the command "flutter build iOS" and then open your iOS directory in xcode then make a proper changes like signing, then run your version with any of the available device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative using Android Studio for Mac**

You dont actually have to run the iOS version from xcode, you do however need to have xcode installed and make sure xcode is setup to [deploy to iOS devices](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices).

You will need to [install the flutter SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#get-sdk) for mac

Alongside xcode [install Android Studio](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup) and in there you will need to install the flutter plugin. Once you restart Android Studio there should be an option on the main menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lixa.png). From here you should be able to open your existing project in Android Studio and deploy the app to the iOS simulator

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Your Project folder contains an Android and IOS folder (if you don't have the IOS one don't worry, i ll get to that). That IOS folder contains an XCode workspace that you have to open in XCode, nothing else required.

Now if you do not have that IOS folder, you will need to build your flutter app for IOS on the Mac. You will need Flutter installed and setup.

Using the Terminal, navigate to your project folder and run "flutter create -path-" Where -path- is where you want your project to be recreated.

Navigate to that recreated project folder, and you should find the IOS folder inside. Open it, and run the workspace in XCode.

I hope that helps, good luck!